# Error: The type specified in the TypeName property of ObjectDataSource could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've got a Datatable with a Sql Connection and am trying to bind that to a GridView, however I get the error that the type specified in the TypeName property could not be found. 
My datatable code looks like this :

```
 protected void ObjectDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{


    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "TestConnectionString";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = conn;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT* FROM TestTable";

        DataTable data = new DataTable();

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

        adapter.Fill(data);

        GridView1.DataSource = data;

    }
```

and the code in the .aspx :

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Column1" HeaderText="Column1" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Column1" >
            <HeaderStyle Width="450px" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Column2" HeaderText="Column2" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Column2" >
                <ItemStyle Width="400px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:BoundField>
        </Column>

    </asp:GridView>
   <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="DataTable" TypeName="data"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Suggestions on what I've done wrong?

Comment: are the actual names of your columns in the datatable are column1 and column2?

Comment: No but I just put that as an example to post the code here- they are called differently in the actual datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how the `ObjectDataSource` control is meant to be used.

If you just want to bind the grid on the first page load, then remove the `ObjectDataSource` control, remove the `ObjectDataSource1_Selecting` event handler, remove the `DataSourceID` property from the `GridView`, and just bind the grid when the page loads:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }
}

private void BindGrid()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("your connection string here"))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TestTable", conn))
    {
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(data);

        GridView1.DataSource = data;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

---

If you want to use the `ObjectDataSource` control, then give it a valid `TypeName` and `SelectMethod`, remove the `ObjectDataSource1_Selecting` event handler, and have the `SelectMethod` return the data:

```
public static class YourDataSource
{
    public static DataTable LoadSomeData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("your connection string here"))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TestTable", conn))
        {
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            adapter.Fill(data);
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server"
    TypeName="YourDataSource"
    SelectMethod="LoadSomeData" 
/>
```

---

If you're using .NET 4.5, you could also use "model binding" to load the data from the code-behind without using a data-source control:

```
public DataTable LoadSomeData()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("your connection string here"))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TestTable", conn))
    {
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(data);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
    AllowSorting="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    SelectMethod="LoadSomeData"
>
<Columns>
    ...
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I've just tried using the way you did it with the ObjectDataSource but I still get the same error. I've also tried the model binding option and got this error: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0 my connection string looks like this:  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("TestConnectionString")). Can you see what's wrong with it? Thanks for the help, it's really appreciated!

Comment: @User: The string `"TestConnectionString"` isn't a valid [connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/). Were you intending to load the connection string from the `web.config` file?

Comment: Yeah I was but I've sorted it so it's all working now. Thanks for the help!